# You can't specify target table 'NAME' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows#comment3999923_18949) solution to my data in table in MySQL DB which has duplicates. And I get such error:

```
SQL Error [1093] [HY000]: You can't specify target table 'NAME' for update in FROM clause


DELETE NAME FROM NAME
WHERE NAME.id NOT IN
   (SELECT MIN(id) 
   FROM NAME GROUP BY col1, col2)
```

Also tried too assign aliases - but without success.
What reason of this error here? 
It generally points that SQL script can produce cyclic process, but here I actually dont see any relevant to this - It is obvious that two selections for `DELETE` and for `SELECT` is detached - engine must do `SELECT`  once firstly and then use it in `WHERE` conditions for `DELETE`.
So - why this error happens and how can I actually deduplicate my table? =)

Comment: Your query looks nothing like the one from the solution that you're trying to apply.  They use a join, whereas you're using `NOT IN`.

Comment: @eggyal My link points to the comment, not to the answer

Comment: Ah, fair enough; I hadn't noticed that.  That comment is SQL Server specific.  You will find the join given in the answer will work in MySQL.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this may help you

```
DELETE  FROM NAME
WHERE NAME.id NOT IN (
                     SELECT * FROM ( 
                                    SELECT MIN(id)  FROM NAME GROUP BY col1,col2
                                   ) AS p 
                      )
```

[Read more](http://dasunhegoda.com/1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-table_name-for-update-in-from-clause/104/)

Comment: But actually I dont understand - if docs says that you cant do subqueries in DELETE (see aib answer) - why your solution works?

Comment: its discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/45498#45498)

Comment: It worked but why we cant specify what we are updating in from. I started learning SQL from [here](sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex8.html). Here they used it in exercise8 and exercise10. Please check.

Answer (score 4):

Your query is correct and would work on other DBMS, but MySQL doesn't allow you to update or delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery. It is documented on the official [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) docs.

It might be fixed on future releases, but currently your query is not supported.

A simple fix would be to put your subquery in a sub-subquery, like in echo_Me answer:

```
WHERE NAME.id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (your subquery) s)
```

this will force MySQL to create a temporary table with the results of your subquery, and since you actually are not selecting from the same table, but from a temporary table, this query will run fine. However, performances might be poor.

You usually get rid of error #1093 by using joins. This is your query in join form:

```
DELETE NAME
FROM
  NAME LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT col1, col2, MIN(id) min_id 
    FROM NAME
    GROUP BY col1, col2) s
  ON (NAME.col1, NAME.col2, NAME.id) = (s.col1, s.col2, s.min_id)
WHERE
  s.min_id IS NULL
```

or you can use this simpler version, which should be the fastest one:

```
DELETE N1
FROM
  NAME N1 INNER JOIN NAME N2
  ON
    N1.col1=N2.COL1
    AND N1.col2=N2.col2
    AND N1.ID > N2.ID
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/560ca/1).

Answer (score 3):

[From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):
"Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery."

Use a proper database engine, or run the queries separately. (Storing the id's programmatically, in between.)

Comment: Can you give the example?

Comment: Of a proper database? PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete records from a table use `DELETE FROM tablename`. You cannot specify a column here. If you want to remove the data from a column please use UPDATE statement to set the value of the column to blank or NULL.

Answer (score -1):

the sintax of delete

not require the name of columns

because mysql delete all data that meet a condition