# MySQL Update from select - You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert datetime to timestamp format in my table 'mytable'. It gives me an error say: **You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause**. Was I wrong with update or converting?

```
UPDATE mytable
SET TimeStampIN = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%h:%i%p') FROM mytable)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [You can't specify target table 'NAME' for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742214/you-cant-specify-target-table-name-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Use another subquery to overcome this restriction of MySQL

```
UPDATE mytable
SET TimeStampIN = 
(
  select * from 
  (
     SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%h:%i%p') FROM mytable
  ) x
)
```