# Update on a table with DISTINCT SELECT in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Suppose I have a table with information about a

```
game (PRIMARY INT id, TINYINT offline)
```

and a second table with detail info about that game:

```
gamedetail (PRIMARY INT id, INT game_id (fk to game table), TINYINT offline)
```

the details get updated frequently and from various programs. There I set the the offline flag of the detail. I have no programmatic possibility of setting the offline flag of the game itself. (I do set the offline flag of the game to 0 however, if I find an online detail).  But I want to set this info in the database via an update query. The idea is this SELECT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT game.id FROM game 
    LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdon 
           ON (gdon.game_id = game.id AND gdon.offline = 0)
    LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdoff 
           ON (gdoff.game_id = game.id AND gdoff.offline = 1)
WHERE gdoff.id IS NOT NULL AND gdon.id IS NULL;
```

This gives me nicely all games where I only have offline gamedetails. So I would like to take this as input for an UPDATE statement like this:

```
UPDATE game SET game.offline=1 WHERE game id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT game.id FROM game 
        LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdon 
               ON (gdon.game_id = game.id AND gdon.offline = 0)
        LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdoff 
               ON (gdoff.game_id = game.id AND gdoff.offline = 1)
    WHERE gdoff.id IS NOT NULL AND gdon.id IS NULL;

)
```

This unfortunately fails in mysql, because of `ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'game' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data`.

My question is how to change my update statement into something that works in mysql?

Edit: corrected the WHERE condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You can't specify target table 'NAME' for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742214/you-cant-specify-target-table-name-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple join no need to have a subquery

```
UPDATE game 
LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdon 
               ON (gdon.game_id = game.id AND gdon.offline = 0)
        LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdoff 
               ON (gdoff.game_id = game.id AND gdoff.offline = 1)
SET game.offline=1
    WHERE gdoff.id IS NOT NULL AND gdon .id IS NULL;
```

Or if you are using subquery you need to give a new alias because in update query you can specify the same table in where clause,and i guess the where condition should be `WHERE gdoff.id IS NOT NULL AND gdon .id IS NULL`

Comment: thx, I corrected the where condition. This is a simplification of the real tables, hence the error. I try your suggestion now

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your query inside a sub query, like this:

```
UPDATE game SET game.offline=1 WHERE game.id IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT game.id FROM game 
        LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdon 
               ON (gdon.game_id = game.id AND gdon.offline = 0)
        LEFT JOIN gamedetail AS gdoff 
               ON (gdoff.game_id = game.id AND gdoff.offline = 1)
    WHERE gdon.id IS NOT NULL AND gdon.id IS NULL;
  ) t
)
```

Comment: huge advantage to this query vs. the OUTER JOIN one in that it uses standard SQL and will work on other databases as well.